# Install4j: Howto copy and modify a launcher at runtime

Tags: copy, runtime, launcher, install4j

In my installer i need a number of launchers, to install them as services, based on the user input. Those Launchers are all the same except for an index in their name.

I dont want to create all those launchers manually because that would be impossible to maintain.

**Is there a way to copy and modify launchers at installer runtime and then install them as a service?**

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to duplicate a service launcher at runtime. You can use an "Install service" action to install several services with different service names. To do that select "Other service executable" in the "Service" property of that action, then you can select and executable *and* a (variable) service name as well as variable arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Usecase too, where i want to have this Possibility of Renaming the Launcher an Runtime.

Assume you want to have a Testinfrastructure, where you want not only to test one Instance of your Programm, but several. And you want to use the Launchers from Install4J to start your Application.

Assume you have 5 Services that need to be started to provide the desired Functionality. Now think of having 10 Instances for 10 Customers, you want to test. Further you want to test it not on 10 different Machines, Docker, VM's, or what ever but on one single Machine.

This isn't possible, since you can't rename the Services at Runtime.
Wolfgang, i understand your Problem. Mine is similar.

I played a bit around with the Launcher.exe.
Perhaps there's a Solution for your Case.
Assuming your desired Launchernames are all off the same Length, like:
 - Launcher_01.exe
 - Launcher_02.exe
 - Launcher_03.exe
 - Launcher_04.exe
 - Launcher_05.exe

You can then generate a Launcher once, with the Name "Launcher_xy.exe".

It's now possible to open up your favorite Hex-Editor an search for "Launcher_xy", rename it to "Launcher_01" and save the Data back to the exe-File. But be aware of not changing the Length of the Name. It won't work, if you'll change the Length.

So if you've changed the Name and afterwards execute

```
Launcher_xy.exe -install non-interactive
```

you will get a new Service called "Launcher_01.exe" under Windows-Services.